# Denoise in EEVEE: Blender 2.91

Tags: edit-mode, eevee-render-engine, denoise

I have recently started using EEVEE to render my images.  However, it is very noisy.  I have not seen an option for denoising, and have tried to use the denoise node in the Compositing tab.

Here is my render using Blender 2.9:
[image]

Can somebody please instruct me on how to denoise my EEVEE renders?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello :). This looks more like denoising artifacts. Is the render shown before or after applied denoising?

Comment: Before, but it looks the same after

Comment: Hey :). In Eevee, the best solution is to increase sample count (how much do you use currently?). The AI denoiser doesn't work that well, because it's meant for ray-tracing engines like Cycles.

Comment: I was at the default 64 samples.  Like most blender artists, I'm really big on reducing render time.